# tuna wrap in non-kosher restaurant

Tags: kashrut-kosher, fish, restaurant

Is there any way to eat a tuna wrap from a non-kosher restaurant, if I have full access to see their ingredients and packaging?

Comment: There may still be a prohibition of Maris Ayin + You do not know what the dishes were used for prior.

Comment: @Gershon Gold, re: dishes - but it's all cold

Comment: Well what if they used a knife for shrimp, then onions then tuna?

Comment: what about dishes being washed together?

Comment: @Gershon, no onions

Answer (score 4):

The question is premised on an unlikely scenario. Did they let you into the kitchen and show you the industrial containers of tuna, mayo, oil, salt, pepper? Did you see them remove the wrap from the packaging? Did they microwave it first to soften it? Was the microwave clean? Did they check the lettuce? Did they cut the tomato without using the ham slicer? Was the work surface clean? Was the knife, spoon and fork new or cleaned properly? Was the mixing bowl clean?

If yes to all of the above, well then you basically made the sandwich yourself with your own kosher components. What's the problem?

Perhaps you meant to ask, "may I cut cold kosher food with a clean non-kosher knife?" The answer is: no, you may not, but post-facto it is OK. See *Shulchan Aruch Yoreh Deah* 121:7 for the right way to do it: by kashering the knife first.

Of course, ask your local rabbi first.

Comment: If you are stuck somewhere without food, there are leniencies. Ask your rabbi. You can also try asking them for new silverware, explaining that you only eat kosher food.

Answer (score 2):

Not recommended. What an amazing coincidence that you are asking this question in Adar, when we will read in the Megilla how Achashverosh served a Glatt Kosher party to the jews and they deserved to die for joining in the party. Let us learn the lessons of Purim that not everything that is seemingly Kosher is recommended.

Comment: Why...........?

Comment: see comments above

Comment: That seems a bit hyperbolic for this question. I think the technical problems here should be sufficient to recommend against consuming such a product. Other than perhaps the problem of how it looks, there are no extra-technical issues that aren't present in any non-Jewish supermarket. And the how-it-looks problem is certainly not comparable to attending a party that celebrates (in part) the downfall of the Jews, desecrates the holy vessels, etc.

Comment: My original answer was simply "Not recommended". However the questioner was looking for further reason which I provided.

Comment: Proving (without sources) that at least one thing which is kosher is not recommended says nothing about this case. Why do you say it isn't recommended when odds seem to dictate that nothing is wrong with it?

Comment: I'm curious, where is that Megilla story from?

Comment: @andrewmh20 - I believe that it is from the Midrashic commentaries on Megillat Esther.